# Running multiple macros at once (different sheets)

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am running multiple macros using VB for two different sheets in Excel.

Sheet1: I can run multiple macro's together:

```
Sub option2()
    CreateTable2
    HeaderChange1
    HeaderChange2
    HeaderChange3
    HeaderChange4
End Sub
```

Sheet 2: I can run multiple macros together (this presents the new data that the macro from sheet 1 has created):

```
Sub option1()
    ClearCols
    CreateTable
    MoveColumns
End Sub
```

Is there any way I can run one macro to complete all the functions at once - instead of running the two above separately?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should replace all your activesheet references to a specific worksheet, add a worksheet info to all the ranges you have without a worksheet info, e.g.

`activesheet.range("A1").copy` becomes `Sheets("Sheet1").range("A1").copy`

`range("A1").copy` becomes `Sheets("Sheet1").range("A1").copy`

Then you can either combine all your macros or run them in one combined macro:

```
Sub RunAllMacros
CreateTable2
HeaderChange1
HeaderChange2
HeaderChange3
HeaderChange4
ClearCols
CreateTable
MoveColumns
End Sub
```

If you still run off the active sheet, you can change the selection in the middle (though selecting in VBA should be avoided unless you want the user to see a selection change)

```
Sub RunAllMacros

CreateTable2
HeaderChange1
HeaderChange2
HeaderChange3
HeaderChange4

Sheets("Sheet2").select

ClearCols
CreateTable
MoveColumns
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can create a new macro to run both options...

```
Sub bothOptions()
    Call Option1
    Call Option2
End Sub
```

Is this what you needed?